# framework7 vuejs clicking on back button loses the content?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-framework-7

I am sure there's a configuration setting somewhere, but not sure where it is at?

I have app page that loads content from axios methods into a listview. Then, I click on the item list and it goes to the next page fine. When I clicked back, the listview loses all the items from the axios request. Is there a way to keep the content within listview without calling the axios methods again?

```
<template id="page-rank"> 
     <f7-page>
         <f7-navbar back-link="Back" sliding>
             <f7-nav-center sliding>Rank</f7-nav-center>
         </f7-navbar>                
         <f7-list media-list>
            <f7-list-item v-for="item in items"
                :link="item.link"
                :media="item.media"
                :title="item.title"
                :subtitle="item.subtitle"
                :text="item.text">
            </f7-list-item>
        </f7-list>
     </f7-page>
 </template>
```

Comment: It depends on how you are using your component, but most likely you'll need some sort of [state management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html). If you are switching your components dynamically there is also the [<keep-alive>](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive) element. If you could provide a more full fledged example, preferably with a jsfiddle or similar, I might be able to help more.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out...I was using the same array for another component, so it basically reset itself. Appreciate the response!